# Rollback of a transaction in case of Gov Limit Error while using AllOrNone false

Tags: governorlimits, rollback, allornone

Will the entire transaction be rolled back in case of Governor Limit exception if I have fired some partial saves done?

e.g. if the gov limit exception of 100 SOQL is hit while execution of contact trigger (initiated in line 3), will the accounts saved will also get rolled back?

```
SavePoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
Database.update(accountList, false);
Databse.update(contactList,false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. An uncaught exception will always roll back the entire transaction, and `LimitException`, which represents governor limit violations, cannot be caught or handled. It will roll back regardless of any save points or `allOrNone` options used to perform DML.